# Access frequencies of an atomic vector in a tibble data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I am doing Exploratory Data Analysis on a tibble data frame. I've never used tibble so I'm experiecing some difficulties.
My tibble data frame has this structure:

```
spec_tbl_df [7,397 x 19] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ X1                     : num [1:7397] 9617 12179 9905 5745 10067 ...
 $ Administrative         : num [1:7397] 5 26 4 3 7 16 4 3 2 0 ...
 $ Administrative_Duration: num [1:7397] 408 1562 58 103 165 ...
 $ Informational          : num [1:7397] 2 9 2 0 1 3 4 5 0 0 ...
 $ Informational_Duration : num [1:7397] 47.5 503.7 28.5 0 28.5 ...
 $ ProductRelated         : num [1:7397] 54 183 82 25 115 86 75 23 27 33 ...
 $ ProductRelated_Duration: num [1:7397] 1547 9676 4729 1109 3428 ...
 $ BounceRates            : num [1:7397] 0 0.0111 0 0 0 ...
 $ ExitRates              : num [1:7397] 0.01733 0.0142 0.01454 0.00167 0.01629 ...
 $ PageValues             : num [1:7397] 0 19.57 9.06 61.3 4.97 ...
 $ SpecialDay             : num [1:7397] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Month                  : Factor w/ 10 levels "Aug","Dec","Feb",..: 8 8 8 1 8 4 8 7 8 8 ...
 $ OperatingSystems       : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 8 2 ...
 $ Browser                : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 5 ...
 $ Region                 : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 2 1 6 4 8 1 1 7 3 ...
 $ TrafficType            : Factor w/ 19 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 12 2 5 10 4 2 4 2 1 ...
 $ VisitorType            : Factor w/ 3 levels "New_Visitor",..: 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 3 ...
 $ Weekend                : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Revenue                : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Now if I use plot_bar to plot the cathegorical data (using DataExplorer package) I have no problem. I would like, for example, to create a boxplot for the cathegorical variable "Month" where for each month I have a boxplot showing how values are distribuited. The problem is that I can't find a way to access the frequencies. If I do the following:

```
boxplot(Month)
```

It creates a single boxplot for all the data (all the months) but it's not helpfull at all. Like this:

[image]

I would like the months on the x axis and the frequencies on the y axis and a boxplot for each month.
I've tried to "extract" the feature month, transform it to a matrix and repeat the process but it does not work.
Here is the variable montht taken alone:

```
> summary(x_Month)
 Aug  Dec  Feb  Jul June  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sep 
 258 1034  123  259  166 1125 2014 1814  327  277
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What values are you plotting against `Month`?

Comment: This is the main problem. As you can see from the vector "x_month" which I created, for each month there are the relative frequencies. I want to plot them for each month. Or, even better, boxplot those frequencies for each single month. Month is categorical variable, frequencies are continous. But I don't know how to "extract" and use those frequencies. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would probably work to create barplots for the frequencies of `Month`:

```
library(ggplot2)

spec_tbl_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Month)) +
        geom_bar()
```

Comment: I dont want to plot the variable Month with X1, they are different features. Inside the feature month, for each month, there are the frequencies. I want to plot these frequencies for each month. Or a boxplot of the frequencies for each month. As you can see from the vector x_month there are frequencies for each month, those are the values i want to work with. I don't know how to "extract" them. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Like, I can put the variable month in X, but how can I put the relative frequencies for each month in y ? how can I access those frequencies inside the feature month ?

Comment: Your `Month` variable is summarised like this: `Factor w/ 10 levels "Aug","Dec","Feb",..: 8 8 8 1 8 4 8 7 8 8 ...`. So it's a factor, it doesn't contain frequencies. Where exactly are you finding your frequencies? Are your frequencies supposed to be the counts of `Month`? Because if so, a boxplot doesn't make sense to plot that data.

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. If I create a new vector (x_month) and I assign to it the feature month, then with summary I can clearly see for each month the number of frequencies (its like a count ?). And if I use the function plot_bar from the package DataExplorer I have a plot of those frequencies for each month. I want to have a boxplot for each month.

Comment: I think you're looking for a barplot, not a boxplot..? It doesn't make any sense to make a boxplot of frequencies. Boxplots are for numeric variables, will show median, lower and upper quartiles, etc. If you just have a count of unique values, it makes no sense to construct a boxplot. There are no summary statistics to create from that.

Comment: No sir, I can do it by using the function plot_bar from DataExplorer. Now I am thinking that maybe a boxplot is not a useful idea in this case. What if i would like to create a pie chart for all the months ? Or a table which show how frequencies are distributed among months ?

Comment: You are right Heds1, I am realizing that boxplot is nonsense in this case. I am sorry. What about a pie chart or a table to summarize how frequencies are distributed among months ?

Comment: If i use the function pie() on x_month (or on Month, it doesn't change) i get an error message " 'x' values must be positive "

Comment: I think in general a pie chart is a bad idea for this sort of data. I've updated the code above to create a barplot; I think that's the most appropriate plot for your data.

Comment: Thanks Heds1, what if I would like to create a table that can resume for each month the % of frequencies over the total ? like: Jan: 12% , Feb: 16% etc.

Comment: I think at this point you can choose to mark the answer as accepted or not, but in any case, make a new question if you have a new one.